# Find the nth Digit of a Number JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I really thought I'd be able to find the solution to my issue but I think the more I look at it the less I can see. Here is my homework:

> Complete the function that takes two numbers as input, `num` and `nth` and return the `nth` digit of `num` (counting from right to left).
>   **Note:**
>   - If `num` is negative, ignore its sign and treat it as a positive value
>   - If `nth` is not positive, return -1
>   - Keep in mind that 42 = 00042. This means that `findDigit`(42, 5) would return 0

Code:

```
var findDigit = function(num, nth) {
  let change = num.toString();
  let find = (change.charAt(change.length - nth) * 1);
  if (nth <= 0){
    return nth;
  } 
  return find; 
}
```

The inputs are:

```
describe("Test", function() {
  it("Examples", function(){
    Test.assertEquals(findDigit(5673, 4), 5);
    Test.assertEquals(findDigit(129, 2), 2);
    Test.assertEquals(findDigit(-2825, 3), 8);
    Test.assertEquals(findDigit(-456, 4), 0);
    Test.assertEquals(findDigit(0, 20), 0);
    Test.assertEquals(findDigit(65, 0), -1);
    Test.assertEquals(findDigit(24, -8), -1);
  });
});
```

My results are:

- Test Passed: Value == 5
- Test Passed: Value == 2
- Test Passed: Value == 8
- Expected: 0, instead got: `NaN`
- Test Passed: Value == 0
- Expected: -1, instead got: 0
- Expected: -1, instead got: -8

Comment: You should also include the inputs in your tests so we have a better idea of which cases your code fails at.

Comment: Sorry Jacob my apologies, I've just updated it thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the first step is to make sure you are removing the negative sign when you convert the number to a string, as the instructions say we can treat them as positive and the negative sign will be taking up a character position when we traverse each character.

The next step is when nth <= 0 we should return a -1 as the instructions tell us explicitly that

> If `nth` is not positive, return -1.

The resulting function would look like:

```
var findDigit = function(num, nth) {
  if (nth <= 0) {
    return -1;
  } 
  let change = num.toString().replace('-', '');
  let find = (change.charAt(change.length - nth) * 1);
  return find; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Joel I really appreciate it, I had a feeling - was the issue but I wasn't sure what to actually do about it. Have a good night!

Comment: @JoelAK it would be better to start by checking if `nth <= 0`, since it doesn't depend on `num` and in that case you've done a useless string replacement and research for a character index inside a string.

Comment: Good call @AlessioCantarella

Answer (score 5):

In the specifications for the function, you should return `-1` when `nth` is negative, not `nth`.

For the test that fails with `NaN`, it is because you are grabbing the `-` and treating it as a digit. You should convert the input to a positive value using `Math.abs()`, which will get rid of the sign.

I believe this should make your tests pass, except for the case where `nth` > `num.length`, which you haven't tested.  You should include a test where `num = 42` and `nth = 5`.

```
var findDigit = function(num, nth){
  if (nth <= 0){
    return -1;
  }
  let change = Math.abs(num).toString();
  let find = (change.charAt(change.length - nth) * 1);
  // I suspect this will fail when nth is larger than the length
  return find; 
}
```

**Edit:** To make sure your code passes the test I described above, use this to easily return `0` in this case:

```
var findDigit = function(num, nth) {
  if (nth <= 0) {
    return -1;
  }
  let change = Math.abs(num).toString();
  if (change.length < nth)
    return 0;
  let find = (change.charAt(change.length - nth) * 1);
  return find; 
}
```

Comment: Hi Jacob, I've tried your original answer and it worked, even when I editted nth to become larger than length. I appreciate your help, I had a feeling - was the issue but I didnt know how I could get around it with what knowledge I have, but you have clarified perfectly so again thank you!

Comment: `(change.charAt(change.length - nth)  *1)` can be simply `change[change.length - nth]`

Answer (score 3):

I have translated your requirements into code and added your test cases:

```js
// Write a function that takes two numbers as input, num and nth
function findDigit(num, nth) {
  // If nth is not positive, return -1
  if (nth <= 0) {
    return -1;
  } else {
    // If num is negative, ignore its sign and treat it as a positive value
    let str = Math.abs(num).toString();
    // Keep in mind that 42 = 00042. This means that findDigit(42, 5) would return 0
    if (nth > str.length) {
      return 0;
    } else {
      // Return the nth digit of num (counting from right to left)
      return str.charAt(str.length - nth);
    }
  }
}

// Test cases
console.log(findDigit(5673, 4) == 5);
console.log(findDigit(129, 2) == 2);
console.log(findDigit(-2825, 3) == 8);
console.log(findDigit(-456, 4) == 0);
console.log(findDigit(0, 20) == 0);
console.log(findDigit(65, 0) == -1);
console.log(findDigit(24, -8) == -1);
```

Comment: Thank you Alessio, I appreciate the time you've taken to help me. The way you have approached the question is so methodical and simple so thank you for showing me that, I'll be practicing all my further tests exactly how you've approached this!

Answer (score 1):

I guess your function would be better off with test results with something like this:

```
var findDigit = function(num, nth) {
  let change = num.toString();
  let val = change.charAt(change.length - nth);
  if (!(val >= 0)) {
    val = 0;
  }
  let find = val * 1;
  if (nth <= 0) {
    return -1;
  } 
  return find; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you i'm making a note of all of this and i'll be reverse engineering it to better understand what happened!